# Second Execution of func init() in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have very simple code, my .go file:

```
func init() {
http.HandleFunc("/", handlerMain)
log.Println("init executed")
}

func handlerMain(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
fmt.Fprintf(w, "TEST")
}
```

and app.yaml:

```
application: newsboard
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1 

handlers:
- url: /.* 
  script: _go_app
```

When Executed at first everything goes fine, this is output from console

```
INFO     2015-10-19 19:28:56,626 devappserver2.py:763] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2015-10-19 19:28:56,652 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:56946
INFO     2015-10-19 19:28:56,655 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2015-10-19 19:28:56,658 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
2015/10/19 19:28:59 init executed
```

But when I Enter http://localhost:8080 I get following:

```
INFO     2015-10-19 19:32:16,394 module.py:786] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4
2015/10/19 19:32:16 init executed
```

So init() somehow is being executed twice. Then, Every time when I reload page everething is ok,"init executed" doesn't appear in console anymore.
My question: Why init() happens twice and is this okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly fine.

The Go AppEngine SDK monitors the application's code base, and whenever it detects changes (e.g. you modified a `.go` source file) it automatically reloads your application. This includes / involves unloading your code and reloading it -  running `init()` functions again.

Basically control over when an app is reloaded - and therefore execution of the `init()` functions - is in the "hands" of the SDK. Try to modify a `.go` file and hit refresh in the browser: you will experience another `init()` function execution.

When you first start your app, all the code is loaded/compiled (and `init()` functions get executed) - this needs to be done in order to report if there are errors. After that the SDK may unload it (not sure - couldn't find relevant docs) and only load it again if a request does happen (which may or may not come anytime soon).

Comment: But what exactly happens when I first visit my localhost page? I thought that it doesn't do anything that could be recognized as code modification